# Use of undefined constant login - assumed 'login' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) when trying to logout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

when ever i want to logout, it always show "*Use of undefined constant login - assumed 'login'*" error. what did i do wrong?

> web.php

```
route::get('/logout','AuthController@logout')->name('logout');

route::get('/','PagesController@home')->name('home');
```

> AuthController.php

```
public function getLogin(){
        return view('login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request){
       if(!\Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
        return redirect()->back();
       }
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

public function logout(){
        \Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route(login);
    }
```

> PagesController.php

```
public function home()
    {
        return view('index') ;
    }
```

main.blade.php

```
<a href="{{route('logout')}}">logout</a>
```

Comment: it is default laravel logout?

Comment: nope, i create it manually

Comment: `return redirect()->route(login);` <- you've missed the `'` marks around `login` so technically you're referencing the constant `login` rather than a string `'login'` - and you get the warning (in future it'll be an error).

Comment: Oh goshhh, i missed it

Comment: Easily done - sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes to look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `login` in qoutation:

```
public function logout(){
        \Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As per your code you need to use quote for it on the below line while using login, so if you do not provide quote it is assuming as constant.
And also there should be a route for it in your route file with the name login as per your question that route also do not exists yet

```
public function logout(){
        \Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public function logout(){
        \Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route(login);
    }
```

**change To :**

```
public function logout(){
        \Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
```